# How can I add a space character into a string in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So, I have to perform text correction. If I met a comma in the text/string, I need to verify if there is space before it in order to eliminate it and if there is space after the comma. If there is not, I need to put one right after the comma. I tried to do this, but only the part with the elimination of the space before the comma worked. When I try to add, I overwrite something (I saw that in the TD) and I can't figure out what.

```
     COMMA:
    CMP BUFFER[SI],00 ; end of text
    JE EXIT
    CMP BUFFER[SI],44 ; 44 is the ascii code for comma
    JNE NEXTC
    CMP BUFFER[SI],44
    JE VERIFY
NEXTC:
    INC SI
    JMP COMMA 
VERIFY:
    CMP BUFFER[SI-1],20H ; 20 ascii code for space 
    JNE VERIFY2         ; if it isn't space, I search if the next element after comma is space
    CMP BUFFER[SI-1],20H
    JE CONDITION
CONDITION:
    MOV CL,L
    SUB CX,SI
    SHR CL,1;   
    XOR CH,CH;
    MOV DI,SI
    JMP REMOVESPACE ; I have space before the comma and I eliminate it
REMOVESPACE:
    MOV DL, BUFFER[DI]
    MOV BUFFER[DI-1],DL ; overwrite the useless space 
    INC DI
    LOOP REMOVESPACE
VERIFY2:
    INC SI
    CMP BUFFER[SI],20H ; if there is space, I jump to the initial stuff, searching for another comma
    JE COMMA
    CMP BUFFER[SI],20H
    JNE CONDITION2 ; if there isn't, I try to add 
CONDITION2:
    MOV CL,L ; L is the no of chars in the buffer
    SUB CX,SI
    SHR CL,1;   
    XOR CH,CH;
    MOV DI,LEN ; LEN also as L but DW
    SHR DI,1
    JMP ADDSPACE
ADDSPACE:
    MOV DL,BUFFER[DI]
    MOV BUFFER[DI+1],DL ; here I try to move the elements, obtaining buffer[si+1] free and then move a space to it
    DEC DI
    LOOP ADDSPACE
    MOV BUFFER[SI+1],20H 
    JMP COMMA
```

I don't know what to do, I think there is a problem with the fact that I can't move all the elements to right because there is no buffer[L+1] or something.

Comment: _" I think there is a problem with the fact that I can't move all the elements to right because there is no buffer[L+1] or something"_ Then you need to make sure that you've got enough space by allocating the space necessary to hold the converted string. Sounds to me like the worst-case scenario is a string consisting only of commas, which would require twice the amount of space as the input.

Comment: [MCVE], you don't show important things like how you define your data, etc... BUT if you have string like ",0", it's in memory as two bytes 44, 48. After adding space you need to finish with three bytes 44, 32, 48. One of the prerequisites is to have large enough buffer, other is to verify your code does modify the memory content like that. Also if this is some kind of formatter and not editor, you can choose to not modify the source data, but only adjust the output to skip/add the spaces as needed, while the source data will be still ugly-formatted. = no `memmove` needed.

Comment: BTW, you can detect the "space comma" case by single cmp, like `cmp word ptr [BUFFER+si], 0x2C20` `jne skip_space_removal` (0x2C = comma, 0x20 = space), in next code the space at BUFFER+si address has to be removed. The "comma not_space" case is more complex but I would keep it [si] and [si+1] centered, like... `cmp [BUFFER+si],','` `jne skip_space_adding` `cmp [BUFFER+si+1],' '` `je skip_space_adding` .. then the next code should insert space at BUFFER+si+1 address.

Comment: what Michael already said about the need of allocated space is completely right. where do you get the string from? Could you return a different string position as result?

Comment: both of the `cmp buffer[...],20` `je conditionX` in front of the "condition:" are unneeded. as are `CMP BUFFER[SI],44` `JE VERIFY` More optimizations possible: don't "calculate" the number of bytes to shift for (backwards-)copying for insert, you know when to stop: when DI reaches SI